# geolocalizacion en ionic 3 retorna siempre la misma latitud y longitud

Tags: ionic, ionic2, ionic-framework, ionic3

Resulta que la geolocalización de ionic3 en mi celular después de un tiempo empieza a retornar la misma latitud y longitud. Es decir durante 30 minutos la geolocalización calcula la latitud y longitud correctamente pero después de un tiempo empieza a retornar la misma latitud y longitud. Ejemplo: durante los 30 minutos retorna diferentes latitudes y longitudes. 6.25...-7591929...

Al cabo de un tiempo siempre retorna la misma latitud y longitud. Es decir, 6.25489, -75.129912. No importa en el lugar donde este siempre retorna 6.25489, -75.129912. No sé si es cache.

Aquí en el método provider tengo

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
```

Las variables declaradas

```
public laS: any = 0;
public loS: any = 0;
```

En el constructor tengo

```
constructor
    (
    public http: Http,
    private geolocation: Geolocation
    ) 
    {
       console.log('Hello GeoProvider Provider');
    }
```

El método para obtener la latitud y longitud tengo

```
lng() {
    var options = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      maximumAge: 0,
      timeout: 5000
    };

      this.subscription = this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then((resp) => {
        //alert(resp.coords.latitude);
        //alert(resp.coords.longitude);
        this.laS = resp.coords.latitude;
        this.loS = resp.coords.longitude;
      }).catch((error) => {
        //console.log('Error getting location', error);
        alert("Error "+error);
      });

  }
```

El método anterior intente quitando options para ver si calculaba una latitud y longitud diferente. Además colocando en maximumAge:0 y tampoco funciona. Retorna siempre lo mismo

Luego en el componente home.ts importo el provider antes mencionado

```
import { GeoProvider } from '../../providers/geo/geo';
```

En el constructor tengo

```
constructor
  (
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public geoProvider: GeoProvider
  ) 
  {}
```

Y el método para llamar la función

```
lng()
  {
    this.geoProvider.lng();
  }
```

Por último en la vista home.html tengo

```
<div>
      <button ion-button color="primary"  (click) = "lng()">Cacular solo latitud y longitud</button>
      <div>
        latitud: {{ geoProvider.laS  }}
      </div>
      <div>
          Longitud: {{ geoProvider.loS  }}
      </div>
  </div>
```

No sé donde estoy cometiendo el error o si es un problema del plugin geolocalización.

Answer (score 0):

Es muy raro el error que está teniendo, esa api de mapas funciona muy bien. 
Le recomiendo que use el método [Geolocation.watchPosition()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition) cómo lo explican [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23701245/4996446), porque el código que ud está publicando, creo que está muy bien para que éste esté funcionando mal. y según veo [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1972161/4996446), explican la diferencia entre [watchPosition()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition) y [getCurrentPosition()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition) y dicen que es mejo y más exacta la propiedad [watchPosition()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition).

Comment: Hola. Gracias pero resulta que con watchposition resulta el mismo problema. Retorna siempre la misma latitud y longitud. Segun lo que habia leido sobre watch es que este calcula las coordenadas cada vez que se cambiara de posicion. Lo habia intentado y mismo problema

Comment: podrías compartir las versiones de: node, npm y la apiMaps. Para poder comprobar que no sea un error de versiones y en lo posible, usar una versión diferente y funcional.

Comment: De node es 8.5.0, npm es 5.3.0 y en cuanto a la version de apiMaps estoy usando es geolocalization de ionic 3. https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/                                             la version de ionic es 3.15.2

Comment: Solo intento obtener la latitud y longitud. Google maps no lo estoy  usando. Este problema he buscado bastante y no le encuentro el problema

Comment: @santiago, pues sería bueno que compartieras el repositorio o crear un Jsfiddle, porque sin poder ver el código es medio-complejo organizarlo.   

Le comparto este [API](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation/) que es más avanzada para geolocalización, [Aquí](https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation-example) hay un ejemplo funcional.